# Is there a way to classify columns as "always null" or "contains not null values" within a SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to categorize columns in a sql query as "always null" or "contains not null values".

In the example output table below, a group by is done on Column 1 and 2, and categorization on Columns 3, 4 and 5. Is there any way to do this in a sql query?

[image: sample output table]

Comment: most probably, you're looking for `case..when` statements. But the question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    CASE WHEN MAX(Column3) IS NULL THEN 'Always Null' ELSE 'Not Null Values Present' END Column3,
    CASE WHEN MAX(Column4) IS NULL THEN 'Always Null' ELSE 'Not Null Values Present' END Column4,
    CASE WHEN MAX(Column5) IS NULL THEN 'Always Null' ELSE 'Not Null Values Present' END Column5
FROM
    TargetTable
GROUP BY
    Column1,
    Column2
```